# Exactness of localization functor for noncommutative rings, and categories with left/right calculi of fractions

Tags: category-theory, noncommutative-algebra, localization

I know that if $\mathsf C$ is a category and $\Sigma$ is some class with a right calculus of fractions then the localization functor $\varphi: \mathsf C\longrightarrow \mathsf C[\Sigma ^-1]$ is right exact.

I'm pretty sure the dual says that if $\Sigma$ also has a left calculus of fractions then $\varphi$ is left exact.

For commutative rings, I know localization is an exact functor.

What about the noncommutative case? Is localization functorial, and is this functor exact?

Also, why, intuitively, does a calculus of fractions make localization half-exact?

Comment: The two "localisation functors" you speak of are not analogous. $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C} [\Sigma^{-1}]$ is more akin to the _ring homomorphism_ $R \to R [S^{-1}]$ than the _functor_ $R \mapsto R [S^{-1}]$.

Comment: @ZhenLin I understand. Then "why" is it that the functor $R \mapsto R [S^{-1}]$ is exact, like the functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C} [\Sigma^{-1}]$?

Comment: There is no common reason. These are facts that drop out of the explicit construction.

Comment: @ZhenLin but the definition of Ore sets is essentially identical to the definitions of calculi of fractions... How can it be there is no connection?

Comment: As I said, you are mixing category levels. Either ask about $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C} [\Sigma^{-1}]$ and $R \to R [S^{-1}]$ or ask about $\mathcal{C} \mapsto \mathcal{C} [\Sigma^{-1}]$ and $R \mapsto R [S^{-1}]$. Incidentally, $\mathcal{C} \mapsto \mathcal{C} [\Sigma^{-1}]$  is _not_ left exact.

Comment: @ZhenLin I will edit my question in a few hours. Regarding the last sentence - why is left calculus of fractions $\implies$ left exactness not the dual of right calculus of fractions $\implies$ right exactness?

Comment: Don't misunderstand me. $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C} [\Sigma^{-1}]$ is  left exact if you have a right calculus of fractions. But I'm talking about $\mathcal{C} \mapsto \mathcal{C} [\Sigma^{-1}]$.